# The method addContributionItem(IContributionItem, Expression) from the type IContributionRoot refers to the missing type Expression

Tags: java, casting, typeerror

I'm trying to code a plugin for eclipse with a menu and submenus, but when I write:

```
additions.addContributionItem(item, null);
```

I have this error:

```
The method addContributionItem(IContributionItem, Expression) from the type IContributionRoot refers to the missing type Expression
```

I looked on the Internet but couldn't find any good solution. Plus I don't fully understand this error. If someone could explain it to me and help me, that'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `org.eclipse.core.expressions` under `Require-Bundle` section in your `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an IMenuManager?

```
IMenuManager manager = new MenuManager();
manager.add(contributionItem);
Menu menu = manager.createContextMenu(getControl());
```